# jquery slide-in when page loads doesn't work for specific site? How do I tell what version of jquery will work for this site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically, I want a div box to slide in on the page when it loads. I tested it on other websites, and html previews, all of which have worked so far. 
It just seems to be that [this](http://poutsu.chatango.com/) specific website doesn't seem to like it, and I can't figure out why.

The HTML:

```
<div id="kitten">
<div class="banner">
bloop
</div>
</div>
```

The script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("div.banner")
.css("margin-left",-$(this).width()) 
.animate({
    marginLeft:0
}, 3000);
</script>
```

The CSS:

```
#kitten{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:920px;
top:0px;
left:0px;
background:white;
}

.banner{
position:fixed;
width:600px;
height:45px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
background:black;
color:white;
text-align:center;
z-index:500;
}
```

I'm jut curious if the website has some sort of way of blocking it, or if I happen to be using the wrong installation of jquery(?) Is there any way to find out what version of jquery to use that will work on there.

**NO. I do not OWN the site, it's just a profile page that I posted some code onto. I'm not "hosting" anything.**

Comment: you got an error 'ReferenceError: $ is not defined' , is your website hosted on wordpress?

Comment: Its that a number of libraries use `$` as an alias. So, depending on the environment you're site is installed on, they might be using `$` for a different one.

Comment: @NicolòCozzani I have no idea. It's basically a profile page of mine on a chatwebsite that I plan to make multiple themes on. If it were hosted on wordpress, is there any way around the issue?

Comment: @wahwahwah How do I find the $ they are using? Sorry, I'm very new to jquery stuff.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to include jQuery library before that your js script

perhaps, "$" <- this object used by other libs, you have to check this link.
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Answer (score 0):

Add JQuery library before your script so that $ can be identified.

Eg:- 
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`

If you are using WordPress, Please convert `$` to 'jquery`

`$(document).ready(function() {`

to

`jQuery(document).ready(function($){`

Comment: Updated. Sorry, I initially put it there, but the editor didn't make it visible.

Comment: i think he already load jquery before the script, if you inspect div #kitten you can see she  add jquery just before the scritpt, but inside a div instead before/after body tags.

Comment: I tried it with body tags, but didn't really work either. So, I just simplified it down as much as I could.

Comment: so why there is HTML tag on your question? how have you developed your website untill now? wordpress or other CMS?

Comment: I posted all the HTML there is. Plus, it's not my site, it's just my profile on it. @NicolòCozzani

Answer (score 0):

Try this, firstly load jquery before body closing tag`</body>`

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

then, create in the same folder of your index.html a file called script.js that should look like this :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("div.banner")
     .css("margin-left",-$(this).width()) 
      .animate({
       marginLeft:0
    }, 3000);
});
```

Now include it in your html just after jquery:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html
```

If still not working try, as @Arshid KV said, to change

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

to

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
```

Comment: I don't have an index.html file, so I don't really understand what you've said.